# How to download file from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I'm trying to make my Download function popup with the file to download, it is outputting the binary of the file to the div when i click the link, how can i make it so that when i click the link, it will instead ask me to download it? I know i can do it with querystring and using headers in php, but can i do it with ajax/javascript in a similar way? thanks, here's what i tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Download(plan_name)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=resp;


            //HOW TO SHOW test.zip in a save-as dialog?
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","fetcher.php?file=/raid0/data/naswebsite/Projects/Projects/07-003_Dawson_Mine/Flight\ Plans/Dawson_Sth_1211_AMG_700.zip");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onClick="Download();">Test Download</a>
<div id="txtHint"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to download a file from an AJAX request.
Instead, you can load the URL in a hidden `<iframe>`.

Comment: Or do what most people do and open a new window with `window.open` and set its target URL, and have the response use the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=whatever` and/or `Content-Type: application/force-download`