# Dropbox API and downloading image with javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have this problem where I get my file in Dropbox with XMLHttpRequest, I have every POST etc. working fine, but when I check my response/responseText looks like this:

```
"�PNG
↵↵
IHDR,,�"    pHYs��↵OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexڝSgTS�=���BK���KoR RB���&*!   J�!��Q�EEȠ�����Q,�↵��!���������{�kּ������>��������H3Q5��B�������.@�↵$p�d!s�#�~<<+"��x��M��0���B�\���t�8K�@z�B�@F���&S�`�cb�P-`'������{[�!�� e�Dh;��V�EX0fK�9�-0IWfH�����0Q��){`�##x��F�W<�+��*x��<�$9E�[-qWW.(�I+6aa�@.�y�2�4���������x����6��_-���"bb���ϫp@�t~��,/��;�m��%�h^�u��f�@����W�p�~<<E���������J�B[a�W}�g�_�W�l�~_�↵]2�v����HX}��sɤ��뾲*,9�4S���=3 _���Yijl���#[����g�M�{��OI�FԍΡ��
�7B|u���>w������7P!��Ïpp�p��ûoο�k~��!!BB� �!@B� �!@B��!!BB� �!@B� �!@B��!!BB� �!@B� �!@B��!!BB� �!@B� �!@BB� �!@B� �!@B��!!BB� �!@B� �!@B��!!BB� �!@B� �!@B���+�h+`/��!@B��!!BB� �!@B� �!@B��!�Z�oj�A   N�fJIEND�B`�"
```

I think that is my picture? How I am able to download it then?

```
function showImage() {
    var foldersFiles = [];
    var data = {
        "path": "/path_to_my_file/mypicture.png"
    }

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer My_Access_Token");  
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Dropbox-API-Arg", JSON.stringify(data));
  xhttp.send();
//    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems like you're successfully downloading the image... what do you want to do with it next? (So far, you're logging it to the console.)

Comment: @smarx Good to know that im currently doing it right. The thing what I have to do now is, how do I get file "physically"? Like when im calling showImage function, it pop ups windows where I can download it. Or even show it somehow on webpage?

Comment: Set `xhttp.responseType='blob'` or `xhttp.responseType='arraybuffer'` and then search for how to use a blob/arraybuffer as the `src` for an `img` tag or use the File API to save to the local disk.

Comment: If you want to download the file, this question seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597516/how-to-download-file-from-javascript . If you want to display the image, this question seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394721/how-can-i-convert-image-binary-from-api-call-to-data-uri-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that works in at least some browsers. Specifically, I believe the download part won't work in IE at all. (I only tested in Chrome, where both techniques do work.)

```
var token = '<REDACTED>';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var imageUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(xhr.response);

        // display, assuming <img id="image"> somewhere
        document.getElementById('image').src = imageUrl;

        // download via the download attribute: limited browser support
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = 'test.png';
        a.href = imageUrl;
        a.click();
    }
};
xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({ path: '/test.png' }));
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works like charm and as you said, this isn't working on IE at least not IE 11, but currently I dont need it.